# How to calculate the cost (bill) of a Google Cloud Genomics Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-genomics

I'm using the [Cromwell engine](https://cromwell.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) on Google Cloud, which submits pipeline run requests: https://cloud.google.com/genomics/reference/rest/v1alpha2/pipelines/run.

Once the pipelines have finished, I am then able to find the Google Cloud operations associated with each pipeline via the labels. However, I can't determine their cost. The Google Cloud billing logs only list the compute engine bills, but they don't show a connection between the compute engine instances and the genomics operations, so I can't work out how to calculate the cost.

How can I calculate the cost of a Google Cloud Genomics Pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you run the pipeline with the correct `labels` specified (explained [here in the API docs](https://cloud.google.com/genomics/reference/rest/v1alpha2/pipelines/run#RunPipelineArgs)), you can filter the billing logs using these labels. In my case, the Cromwell engine was doing this automatically for me, so I didn't have to do anything extra.

When you want to analyse the bills, you **have** to [export the data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery), you can't [export the data to a file](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file), because that doesn't give you the required fields.

Once the bills load into BigQuery (took about 4-5 hours for me), you can run the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(cost)
FROM `PipelineBilling.gcp_billing_export_v1_BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID`, UNNEST(labels) as l
WHERE l.key = 'cromwell-workflow-id' AND l.value = 'cromwell-MY-WORKFLOW-ID'
```

This will return a single number, which is the total cost of pipeline with a label called `cromwell-workflow-id`, with a value of `cromwell-MY-WORKFLOW-ID` (however this label will be different if you're not using Cromwell).